# Setting up a new domain Heart Internet

Tags: html, wordpress, dns, hosting

I've never done this before so I'm very confused and don't want to start changing things in my heart internet account unless I know what I'm doing. I basically want to create a new domain using an existing one. Like this exsiting-domain.co.uk/new-domain This will be a WordPress site incase that matters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to implement an Addon Domain.

[What is an Addon Domain?](https://support.ehost.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-an-addon-domain)